# How can I make a CGRect move randomly around the screen so long as the user is touching it?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like for a rectangle move to move around the screen randomly when the user holds his/her finger on it, and stop moving if the user's finger moves off of it. In other words, so long as the user is able to keep up with it, it will keep moving. How should I go about doing this?

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 157, y: 398, width: 100, height: 100) // create rect
let view = UIView(frame: rect) // create view for rect
view.backgroundColor = .red // color rect
self.view.addSubview(view) // display rect
```

Comment: you can use touchBegan and touchEnded or touchCancelled method to find touched location and move your view with those points.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use touch Methods to move your view

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let location = touch.location(in: self.view) //Gives you CGPoints
    YourView.frame = CGRect(origin: location, size: Your size here>
}
```

That might help!

Comment: Thank you! I'll experiment around with that.